# BIGQUERY --disable_ssl_validation in Command Tool

Tags: ssl, google-bigquery, google-cloud-shell

Trying to disable ssl_validation in Google Cloud Shell (Command Tool).
By this command:

```
bq --disable_ssl_validation=[True]
```

give me

```
FATAL Flags parsing error: flag --disable_ssl_validation=[True]: ('Non-boolean argument to boolean flag', '[True]')
```

How to do it correctly?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Try without the brackets

Comment: I want to disable SSL verification checking. This is one way how can i do it, i think.

Comment: If you know some others, would be appreciate your advice!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`--disable_ssl_validation` global flag](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_global_flags).

Look at the [BigQuery command line official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool#general_usage) for how to use it:

`bq --global_flag [ARGUMENT] bq_command --command-specific_flag [ARGUMENT]`